# Auto-complete jQuery in eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-neon

I use the eclipse javascript neon version.
When I type `do` and press `Ctrl + Space` there appears the suggestion for `do while` but none for `document`. If I used `document` once it appears in future uses but I want that it suggests all the possible reasonable continuations.
In a JS Project -> JavaScript Resources are two libraries.
ECMAScript Built-In Library and ECMA 3 Browser Support Library.
In the second are all the methods I'm interested but they don't show up in the auto-completion before I use the explicitly.

Things that I read on stackoverflow that did not work:

- `Window → Preferences → JavaScript → Editor → Content Assist → Restore Defaults`. For some it resolved the problem but for me it did not work.
- Make new Project and copy files
- `Window → Preferences → JavaScript → Editor → Content Assist → Advanced → Other JavaScript Proposals` are already checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately autocompletion of javascript code does not work in Eclipse Neon for this moment. The reason is desribed in this bug's answer: [Eclipse bug description](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507782).
This problem can be solved by installing Tern plugin in Eclipse. Detailed instruction can be found here: [Tern installation guide](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Eclipse-IDE).

You can also downgrade eclipse to Mars version, where autocompletion works out of the box, however it supports only older versions of javascript.